# Time complexity of bubble sort with single for loop

Tags: data-structures, bubble-sort

I studied that bubble sort is an O(n^2) algorithm. But I designed an algorithm which looks as O(n). The following is my code:

```
void bubbleSort(int[] arr) {
int counter = 1, i = 0;
int N = arr.length-counter;
for(i=0; i<N; ){
  if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
    arr[i+1] = temp;
  }
  i++;
  if(i == N){
    N = arr.length - (++counter);
    i = 0;
  }
}
```

There is one for loop and the counter i is set when it is equal to N. According to me the loop is O(n) and it resets for n-1 times. So, it becomes O(n) + O(n-1) = O(n).
Am I correct? If not what should be the complexity of this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are not correct. Having one loop doesn't mean it's `O(n)`. You have to take into consideration how many steps are executed.

Your loop gets re-initialized when `i == N`. You are right about - the loop gets re-initialized `(n-1)` times. Now each time loop is executed the then value of `N` times. So it's not `O(n) + O(n-1)` rather it's `O(n*(n-1))` which eventually leads to `O(n^2)`.

For example -

```
at first pass, loop will be executed (N) times. then N will be re-initialized to (N-1)
at second pass, loop will be executed (N-1) times. then N will be re-initialized to (N-2)
...
...
this will go on in total of (n-1) times.
```

So it will be - `O(N + (N - 1) + (N - 2) + ... + 1)`, which will be evaluated into `O(n^2)`

For experimental purpose you can initialize a counter globally. and check what's the value of total steps executed by your program to check what's actually going on -

```
void bubbleSort(int[] arr) {
int counter = 1, i = 0;
int total = 0;
int N = arr.length-counter;
for(i=0; i<N; ){
  total++;
  if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
    arr[i+1] = temp;
  }
  i++;
  if(i == N){
    N = arr.length - (++counter);
    i = 0;
  }
}
printf(%d", total); // this will give you total number of steps executed. check for various value of n
```

Answer (score 0):

your loop is initializing inside your outer loop n-1 times so

loops will be executing in following way

inner loop for n-1 times for each iteration of outer loop which is n iterations of outer loop * n-1 iterations of inner loop = (n*n-1) = n2 making it's complexity O(n2)

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies within your own statement:

> There is one for loop and the counter i is set when it is equal to N. According to me the loop is O(n) and it resets for n-1 times. So, it becomes O(n) + O(n-1) = O(n). Am I correct? If not what should be the complexity of this code.

- There is only one loop. Correct.
- The time complexity of that loop is O(n). Correct.
- The loop resets for n-1 times. Correct.
- But the calculation is wrong.

If the loop resets for n-1 times,  the complexity becomes:
O(n)+O(n-1)+O(n-2)+....+O(1) which essentially is O(n^2).